# SwiftUI Menu Picker Style shows strange double arrow

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-picker, swiftui-menu

Basically I am using Menu Picker Style for display a set of numbers. I prefer it over Menu because it doesn't have checkmark in front of the selected item and because I need to change the text of the menu it takes time to re-render it if the new item is longer than the previous.
When using the picker style I get these double arrows which annoy me and so far haven't found solution for them.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = "Red"
    let colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Black", "Tartan"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Select a paint color", selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(colors, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.menu)

            Text("Selected color: \(selection)")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I expect it to look something like that. (This photo is taken from normal Menu but as I said before it has more negatives so I don't need it)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try as below with Menu it is possible to display the checkmark

```
struct ContentView: View {

let colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Black", "Tartan"]
@State var index = 0
@State var selectedColor = "Red"
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Menu{
            ForEach(Array(colors.enumerated()), id: \.offset){index, color in
                Button(action: {
                    self.index = index
                    self.selectedColor = color
                }, label: {
                    HStack{
                        Text(color)
                        if selectedColor == colors[index]{
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        } label: {
            Text(colors[index])
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2)
        }
        Text("Selected Color \(colors[index])")
        
    }
}
}
```